# Opencv can't show multiple streams

Tags: c++, opencv, network-programming

i'm having trouble to open two parallel camera streams with opencv. So i have two cameras, both streaming via UDP broadcast. The one on the ip 239.192.140.11 and the other one on 239.192.140.12 both on port 5004. If i open one camera at a time the stream works perfectly fine, but if i want to use both cameras, only one camera image is shown in both windows. So here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
  cv::VideoCapture camera2("rtp://239.192.140.12:5004");
  cv::VideoCapture camera1("rtp://239.192.140.11:5004");
  while(1) {
    char key = (char)cv::waitKey(10);
    cv::Mat frameR;
    cv::Mat frameL;
    camera2 >> frameR;
    camera1 >> frameL;
    if( key  == 27 ) { 
      break;
    }   
    cv::imshow("Left", frameL);
    cv::imshow("Right", frameR);
  }
}
```

As i said above the window "Left" and "Right" show both the same image, that is from camera2. I even tried to compile one program for the left and one for the right camera. They worked fine on their own, but on the second i let them run in parallel the program for the left camera switches the image and also shows the image from the right camera. However, if i try to open both streams with vlc player, it works. Is this a network related problem, or is it opencv? Or a a mixture of both?

Comment: What happens if you change the port number of one of the cameras? Also if you don't mind me asking how did you stream the video via UDP? I am working on something similar and I would like to know some details about you approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm currently not able to change the camera's configuration.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark (don't have access to webcam right now): perhaps the rtsp adress requires additional login info? Something like rtsp://username:password@ipadress:port. That's how I do things in my project.

Comment: The stream itself works. The problem is that one of the streams is "overwritten" by the other one. I don't think that credentials could cause such a problem.

Comment: If you try camera 1 alone does it work?

Comment: Yes, both cameras work fine, if they are alone.